# Trigger (before update) not working. It works in a local PostGIS installation with same table structure and data

Tags: carto

A before insert/update trigger on one of my CartoDB tables is not being raised. **Same trigger is working in a local installation of PostGIS**.

[This](https://libregis.cartodb.com/tables/foursquare_checkins/public) is my source table. And here, the trigger's code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_geom_column()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  coords_array varchar[] := ARRAY[2];
BEGIN
  if new.map_url is null then
    raise exception 'map_url cannot be null';
  end if;

  -- Get coords using regexp_matches
  select regexp_matches(NEW.map_url, 'center=(-?[\d]*\.[\d]*),(-?[\d]*\.[\d]*)&') into coords_array;
  NEW.the_geom = CDB_LatLng(coords_array[1]::numeric, coords_array[2]::numeric);

  return NEW;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;

drop trigger if exists update_geom_column_trigger on foursquare_checkins;
CREATE TRIGGER update_geom_column_trigger
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON foursquare_checkins
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_geom_column();
```

**Every time there's a new insertion in my CartoDB table, all geometry fields of all rows are set to null**. But the same trigger is working in my local PostGIS.

May it be something related with CartoDB itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your table is a Sync Table. Unfortunately, on each sync, **the triggers of the sync tables are dropped**.

Time ago we reported this into the CartoDB repo for keeping triggers through synchronizations, but it seems that the team hasn't worked on that yet: https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb/issues/1941

Comment: Wow, and I was the one who opened the ticket... didn't remember that. Of course, that explains the problem. Silly me... Many thanks!